# Error when setting up eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When trying to install the ADT plugin for eclipse I follow the instructions and get these errors in the Android SDK Manager:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Unknown Host https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml, reason: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Done loading packages.
```

I was wondering if anyone else has had these problems as well and how they fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? It must be set in eclipse's preferences => General => Network Connection.

Comment: Nope, no proxy. That's what makes it so weird.

Comment: I seem to randomly run into this issue too, so I usually end up downloading the updated ADT as zip file and provide that as update location. I know, it's not a fix, but at least it's a fairly easy and fast workaround. I suppose you already tried the "http" suggestion from the [how-to-install section](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)?

Comment: @Ian34 Your provider might have setup a proxy that's invisible for you. In a chat we could try to check this out (when you try to access a specific web page, I could tell you the ip-address I'm seeing in the apache log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider redownloading eclipse and putting it in a fresh location. Eclipse... is good when it works, but it's a swing and a miss when it doesn't.
Otherwise, make sure everything you put in the URL is exactly correct. I remember I once had a space in my URL and it wouldn't download, and it took me like 20 minutes to figure out why my copy/pasted URL would not work. I felt pretty dumb afterwards.

Comment: Tried that and still the same problems

Comment: Is there a way to manually install the SDK/AVD manager? Perhaps a manual way to install the plug in?

Answer (score 0):

If I paste that URL into my browser I get XML back:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml

This one works, too:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I know what it's not.  Those URLs are valid.

Update: My first response whenever I get an error is to paste it into a Google search.  I usually find out that I'm not alone.  Maybe the first link can help you:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21359

Comment: Yes, when I open them in my browser I get the XML as well.